# Extract Table from result of searched webpage using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I need to extract table from result of searched webpage which provide VIN decoder. I tried the following codes many times but I failed to extract. Actually, I tried modify code that someone uploaded but it doesn't occur error but extract nothing. It needed to bring vin code from sheets(1) and Add to end of URL. Also, result for searched vin decoder web site has so many tables that I couldn't specify table that I need.

```
Sub WebScrape()

Dim ie As Object, i As Long, strText As String

Dim doc As Object, hTable As Object, hBody As Object, hTR As Object, hTD As Object, hHead As Object
Dim tb As Object, bb As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, hth As Object, hh As Object

Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

For i = 2 To 386
pagenum = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False

y = 1 'Column A in Excel
z = 1 'Row 1 in Excel

ie.navigate "https://en.vindecoder.pl/" & pagenum


Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


Set doc = ie.document
Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
For Each tb In hTable
'tTable > thead > tr > th
Set hHead = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
For Each hh In hHead
Set hTR = hh.getElementsByTagName("tr")
For Each tr In hTR

Set hth = tr.getElementsByTagName("th")
y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
For Each th In hth
Debug.Print th.innerText
ws.Cells(z, y).Value = th.innerText
y = y + 1
Next th
DoEvents

Next tr
Exit For

Next hh
'th.innerText


Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
For Each bb In hBody

Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
For Each tr In hTR

Set hTD = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
For Each td In hTD
Debug.Print td.innerText
z = 2
ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innerText
y = y + 1
Next td
DoEvents
z = z + 1
Next tr
Exit For
Next bb
'Exit For
Next tb
ie.Quit
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are fetching the page numbers from the sheet, appending it to the URL, launching it, looping through the tables, and trying to fetch the data. Here, I suggest you first try to manually perform the whole operation and see whether it works. When I try to test it manually, I noticed that when I append a number after the URL and pressing enter again redirects to the same page. This means if I append like this `https://www.vindecoder.pl/1` it again loads the `https://www.vindecoder.pl/` page and we can see something is wrong here.